# ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP()) returning first lookup for all results

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

I'm trying to use the following formula:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP( $E2 & $G2, { ARRAYFORMULA (SKUs!$A2:$A & SKUs!$B2:$B ), SKUs!$D2:$D }, 2*SIGN(ROW($E2:$E)), FALSE))`

to retrieve SKUs from a separate sheet in the same document. However, my column is only returning the first value over and over again to fill the column.

Current sheet:

```
   E              G             H (contains formula)
chicken        sandwich        456
duck           sandwich        456
turkey         whole           456
```

SKUs:

```
   A              B             D
chicken        sandwich        456
duck           sandwich        789
turkey         whole           123
```

I've tried changing nearly every individual piece of the formula that made sense, but it continues to just return the SKU of the first item when it looks it up. I did verify, however, that it is properly `VLOOKUP`ing the first item. (that's not the first item in the SKUs list).

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

<sub>I posted this issue on Google Docs Help Forum as well</sub>

Answer (score 2):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(E2:E4&G2:G4,{SKUs!A:A&SKUs!B:B,SKUs!D:D},2,0))
```

You were getting 3 same values because you were only looking up E2&G2.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Didn't realize I needed to specifiy the entire column, altohugh that makes sense. Changed to :=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP( $E2:E & $G2:G, { ARRAYFORMULA (SKUs!$A2:$A & SKUs!$B2:$B ), SKUs!$D2:$D }, 2*SIGN(ROW($E2:$E)), FALSE)) 
and now everything works great! And it updates for new entries as well. Thanks so much! :)

Comment: @|'-'| (Sorry, I've been sick since Nov) First part -- gotcha. Second part -- Is there a way to create the inner table without using the second ARRAYFORMULA?